# ckeditor: mediaembed plugin won't work

Tags: ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor for my site.

Now I found the plugin called "MediaEmbed". I need it for embedding YouTube videos.

I installed it and the integration worked fine, but embedding won't work.

When you paste the code into the text area in the embedding dialog and then click on OK in IE and Chrome nothing happens and in Firefox it just adds a image as a flash-content-placeholder.

Let's say the flash-content-placeholder image would be just in the wysiwyg interface, but then i should get the embed code when I click on "view source" - but no, there you just see the source of the placeholder image div and img tag.

Then let's say the embed code is saved internally, so I save the file I create with CKEditor, and the out I get is just what I entered without the stuff the MediaEmbed plugin has generated at all.

How to fix this?

Please help!

Yours Joern.

Answer (score 0):

use firebug and see, it'll be giving a cross domain error. the plugin has a bug. use try catch in the place where is accesses the windows.name property for a workaround.

Answer (score -2):

Try istead [ckeditor youtube plugin](http://puszki.net/ckeditor-youtube-plugin/)

Comment: that's a really ugly solution, ain't there additional alternatives?